# Confirmación de envio de formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola me gustaría saber como mostrar un mensaje al usuario, de que el formulario se envío correctamente. Decir que soy novato y seguramente tenga errores, también estoy abierto a añadir JS si hiciese falta.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" class="formulario-contacto">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono (Opcional)">
      <select class="asunto-formulario" name="asunto">
        <option value="asunto">Elija un asunto</option>
        <option value="presupuesto">Presupuesto</option>
        <option value="encargo">Encargo</option>
        <option value="pedido">Pedido</option>
        <option value="contratacion">Contratación</option>
        <option value="mas info">Más información</option>
        <option value="otros">Otros</option>
      </select>
      <textarea name="mensaje" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Escriba aquí su mensaje" required></textarea>
      <input class="enlacecurri" type="submit" name="mensaje" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Y este seria el PHP:

```
<?php
  $destino= "adurba90@gmail.com"
  $nombre = $_Post["nombre"];
  $email = $_Post["email"];
  $telefono = $_Post["telefono"];
  $asunto = $_Post["asunto"];
  $mensaje = $_Post["mensaje"];

   $contenido = "Nombre: " . $nombre . "\nEmail: " . $email . "\nTelefono: " . $telefono . "\nMensaje: " . $mensaje;

  mail($destino, "Contacto, $contenido")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu página PHP compruebas el envío de email y pones el mensaje:

```
if (mail($destino,$contacto,$contenido)) {
   echo "<p style='font-size:20px;'>El formulario se ha enviado correctamente</p>";
} else {
   echo "Ha habido un error al enviar el formulario, inténtalo de nuevo por favor";
}
```

Le puedes dar formato con etiquetas html o guardarlo a modo de variable que envíes por URL (get) si tienes preparada una página destino tras el envío.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda @Carmen . me gustaría aprovechar para hacer hacer 2 preguntas relativas. Como selecciono dicha etiqueta HTML para darle estilos CSS y si podría añadirse un "else" si hubiese algún error.

Comment: Edito la respuesta para responder a ambas Adrián

Comment: Reitero muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: No hay de qué Adrián, de eso se trata.